# Merge previous version of current branch to other branch in git

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I have branch A_mybranch. I have done several commit for feature A then several commits for feature B.
Now I want to merge only the commits for feature A to other branch lets say master branch.

Since I have done commits consecutively. It means after feature A commits I started committing for feature B. I tried to revert my local workspace to feature A using following:
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
Now my local workspace head to commits with feature A.

How can I merge these changes to other master branch?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a history like this:

```
-*--*--*--A1--A2--A3--B1--B2--B3 [A_mybranch]
        \
         \--*--*--*--*--* [master]
```

If you want to merge commits A1..A3 into master, it is simply as:

```
git checkout master
git merge <A3 commit id>
```

That's all.